# Differential equation to calculate an investors fortune at time T

Tags: mathematical-economics

An investor has to investment opportunities. At time t his fortune has the value $v(t)$. In the first alternative he can put all his money into a bank account with interest rate $r(t) > 0$. The other option is to invest all his money in a stock which pay continuous dividends.  At time t the stock pays $\pi(t)$. There is no uncertainty regarding the development in stock price.

Assuming $v'(t) + \pi(t) = r(t)v(t)$ holds and $r(t) = r$ and $\pi(t) = \pi$, find an expression for the investors fortune $v(t)$ if he wants to sell the stock at time T>t.

I have tried to solve $v'(t) + \pi = rv(t)$:
$\frac{1}{v(t) - \frac{\pi}{r}} (\frac{dv}{dt}) = r\\\\
ln|v(t) - \frac{\pi}{r}| = rt +C\\\\
v(t) = e^{rt+C} + \frac{\pi}{r}$

I am not sure I understand the intuition behind this, so I am wondering where to go from here.

Comment: In the first equation, it looks like he has invested in both the bank and the stock, is that correct?